# How can magnet field go through non-transparent medium?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

We know that the change in the magnetic field is carried on electromagnetic waves so when magnets move relative to each other they radiate. But if the medium is not letting em cross in some length then the change in the magnetic field is blocked which means they won't be able to feel a force on each other if there is a medium that blocks the EM wave so do magnets produce radiation in length that cannot be blocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, electromagnetic response of media is frequency-dependent, e.g. gamma-particles and x-rays can go through most things.

You are interested in magnetic field due to moving magnets - that would be very low frequencies: hertz, milli-hertz etc. I guess a lot of media are transparent at those frequencies.

One needs to be particularly careful when working with phenomena where you move magnet or charge from one place to another and leave it there. Such analysis should really be done in time-domain since there is no lower frequency cut-off there. Dispersive (frequency-dependent) response would then become a response function of the material.

As far as your question regarding media that block magnets - [Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect) in superconductors comes to mind. Superconductors will block any (static) magnetic field as long as it is below the critical value.